# Python, Tkinter: NameError: global name 'Combobox' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have created a combobox for my gui application in Python but I have been getting this error when declaring my combobox in my **init** function:

`TypeError: 'Combobox' object is not callable`

Here is the code I am using for this:

```
class ProgramingPractice(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ProgramingPractice, self).__init__()
        self.variableCombo_value = StringVar()
        self.variableCombo = ttk.Combobox()

     def questionVariables(self):

        self.variableCombo_value = StringVar()
        self.variableCombo(self.formSize, textvariable = self.variableCombo, state = 'readonly')
        self.variableCombo['values'] = ('Month', 'Year', 'Age', 'Day')
        self.variableCombo.pack()
```

I have tried different solutions to this problem but I have either got an Attibute error or a name error.

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

This is the smallest I can make the code while still getting the error:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class ProgramingPractice(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ProgramingPractice, self).__init__()
        self.formSize()
        self.variableCombo_value = StringVar()
        self.variableCombo = ttk.Combobox()


    def formSize(self):
        self.geometry("700x450+200+200") # Sets the size of the gui

    def questionVariables(self):

        self.variableCombo_value = StringVar()
        self.variableCombo.configure(self.formSize, textvariable = self.variableCombo_value, state = 'readonly')
        self.variableCombo['values'] = ('Month', 'Year', 'Age', 'Day')
        self.variableCombo.pack()


pp = ProgramingPractice()
pp.questionVariables()
```

Comment: What exactly is `ttk`, how did you import it? Also, Python 2 or 3?

Comment: ttk is the tkinter themed widget set, from tkinter import ttk

Comment: You do not get the error in `__init__`, but in the 2nd line of `questionVariables`. Try `self.variableCombo.configure(stuff)`. Also, the `textvariable` parameter should probably be the `StringVar`, not the combobox itself...

Comment: @tobias_k By using the `self.variableCombo.configure(stuff)` I know get the error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'items'` I am not sure what 'items' is.

Comment: Where you do `self.variableCombo(....)` you are trying to use the widget as a callable - you probably want `self.variableCombo.configure(width=self.formsize, textvariable.....)`

Comment: You will have to show more code then. Try to find a minimal runnable example that still produces the error.

Comment: @tobias_k I have added the code I am using removing all unnecessary code

Comment: In the call to `configure`, try `self.formSize()` i.e. the result of the function, not the function itself. Also you probably want to use `textvariable=self.variableCombo_value`. And call `pp.mainloop()` to actually show the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
textvariable = self.variableCombo_value
```